# Is it possible to add a custom component to a Preference Activity in android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

Is there any way to add custom component in preference activity in order to change value for the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any custom component that extends [android.app.Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)

Or if it should be a View - create a layout, but you must include a ListView with android.R.id.list in your layout for the PreferenceScreen

```
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color" >

    <YourCustomComponentView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just setContentView() it before adding any preference.